# How can I dynamically refer to user-specific directories?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run a code that opens user directories on different servers. Right now, it's hard-coded like this:

```
my $existingdir= '/home/nelly/Desktop';
```

Is there any way that I can dynamically define this directory without hard-coding it, so that it works for whoever is the current user?

Comment: Well, the information has to come from somewhere. Where do you want it to come from?

Comment: Are you asking for the shorthand for home, `~/Desktop`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make my code universal for another home machine and not just mines. Since it is hard-coded, if another person was to try to run this code, it wouldn't work because of the path name. Would it be best for the person to just enter the name for the system, /home/input_here/Desktop?

Comment: @ARGV[0] is the best option when you run your code in the terminal put the name of the file after the line to open your perl code, e.g. perl test.pl words.exe, it will automatically store the path for words.exe in @ARGV[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a Unix user's home path you can use the `$ENV` hash.

```
my $existingdir = "$ENV{HOME}/Desktop;"
```

Answer (score 1):

[File::HomeDir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::HomeDir) is a cross platform module that can be used to get user-specific paths on the current machine.

```
use File::HomeDir;

# Modern Interface (Current User)
$home     = File::HomeDir->my_home;
$desktop  = File::HomeDir->my_desktop;
$docs     = File::HomeDir->my_documents;
$music    = File::HomeDir->my_music;
$pics     = File::HomeDir->my_pictures;
$videos   = File::HomeDir->my_videos;
$data     = File::HomeDir->my_data;
$dist     = File::HomeDir->my_dist_data('File-HomeDir');
$dist     = File::HomeDir->my_dist_config('File-HomeDir');

# Modern Interface (Other Users)
$home    = File::HomeDir->users_home('foo');
$desktop = File::HomeDir->users_desktop('foo');
$docs    = File::HomeDir->users_documents('foo');
$music   = File::HomeDir->users_music('foo');
$pics    = File::HomeDir->users_pictures('foo');
$video   = File::HomeDir->users_videos('foo');
$data    = File::HomeDir->users_data('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking how to locate the current user's desktop, which you can do as follows:

```
my $desktop = "$ENV{HOMEDRIVE}\\$ENV{HOMEPATH}\\Desktop";
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can remove the hard-coded. Store directory path in config.txt file in app or software directory.

And you can re-write that file if directory is changed.

If you know ini file, then its better. You can store other options in ini file too.

I use ini to store user data, like startup minimize, skin settings, user info, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The %ENV hash is a built in variable that holds environment settings like your home directory, $ENV{HOME}. Use the Data::Dumper module to see what ENV holds in your script.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( %ENV );
```